# Behavior of a source with internal resistance connected in parallel with a resistor $R$

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-resistance

For a source with electromotive power $E$  with internal resistance $ r $ connected in series with a resistor $ R $, we have: $I = \frac{E}{r+R}$.

Is there any mathematical development that describes the current value when the connection is made in parallel? As well as for which $R$ value the current and the dissipated power is maximum.

I found in the books only deductions for when the connection is made in series.

Comment: The series and parallel connections are the same aren't they? Have you drawn a diagram to show the difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any mathematical development that describes the current value
> when the connection is made in parallel? As well as for which R value
> the current and the dissipated power is maximum.

Not sure why you think there is a difference between a load resistor connected in series with the combination of the internal resistance of the electromotive power (voltage) source, and a load resistor connected in parallel with the combination of the internal resistance and electromotive power source. As @sammy gerbil pointed out, the series and parallel combination are the same thing, because the internal resistance of the power source is internal to the voltage source, such as a battery shown in the diagram below. The load resistor can only be connected across the battery terminals. You can't put it inside the battery in parallel with the internal battery resistance $r$.

That said, maximum power is delivered to the load resistor $R_L$ when $R_L$ equals the internal resistance $r$ of the voltage source, according to the maximum power transfer theorem which states:

*To obtain  maximum external power from a source with a finite internal resistance, the resistance of the load must equal the resistance of the source as viewed from the output terminals of the source.*

Proof:

For a source voltage Source $E$ with internal resistance $r$ in series with a load resistor $R_L$, the power dissipated in the load resistor $R_L$ is given by

$$P_{L}=I^{2}R_{L}$$

The current $I$ is

$$I=\frac{E}{r+R_{L}}$$

Substituting for $I$ into the previous equation gives

$$P_{L}=\biggr(\frac{E}{r+R_{L}}\biggl)^{2}R_L$$

$$P_{L}=E^{2}\biggr(\frac{R_{L}}{(r+R_{L})^{2}}\biggl)$$

For maximum power in $R_L$, the first derivative of $P_L$ with respect to $R_L$ is zero, or

$$\frac{dP_{L}}{dR_{L}}=0$$

Going through the math (left to you for exercise), you will obtain $$R_{L}=r$$

Hope this  helps.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The internal resistance,r , is not accessible to connect in parallel.  Only one node of that resistance is accessible... the node at the end of the battery (or other source of the EMF like a solar cell).  That's why it's called an *internal resistance*, it's always there and you can't bypass it! Your question suggests that you can bypass it by connecting the two resistors r and R in parallel.  That can't be done.

Comment: I think I expressed myself poorly. My question is whether this expression changes when resistor R is connected in parallel with the source. In the examples I saw, R is always connected in parallel with the battery.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.  Series and parallel don't mean anything in this case when there is only one element in addition to the source.  The resistor is connected to one side of the battery and the other... The resulting current  is as you indicate.  There is no other way to connect with 2 elements.  If you had another resistor then there would be multiple ways to connect.